# GIT: How to remove a folder and its contents from Initial commit?

Tags: git, git-commit

How to remove a folder and its contents from Initial commit?

I have an initial commit having several directories. Then a lot commits based on it.

Example:

```
Commit A, having the following directories & files:
A/aaa.txt
B/bbb.txt
C/ccc.txt

A - B - C - D - E - F
```

I would like to delete directory B & C from initial commit A.
Then 
    - create B1 branch with B/bbb.txt.
    - create C1 branch with C/ccc.txt.

So finally the tree would look like this:

```
A(modified) - B1 - C1 - B - C - D - E - F
```

How to get this result?

Thanks!

EDIT1: I would like to remove the directory only from the Initial commit.
Thus I think it is different from the other question, and not duplicate.

Comment: Use `git filter-branch` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158271/1440565).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History under: Removing a File from Every Commit

Answer (score 3):

You cannot modify *any* existing commit.  This is a fundamental Git guarantee: any content, once saved, is saved that way *forever*, by the hash ID generated when saving it.

You *can* simply *stop using* any existing commit(s), and of course you can always make *new* commits.  Hence you'll need to make a new commit that's *almost* the same as commit `A`, but not quite *exactly* the same:

- extract existing commit `A`;
- remove the unwanted files;
- and last, make a new root commit `A'` that's a copy of `A` in most ways, except for the fact that those files are now gone.

You now have:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- old-master

A'   <-- new-master
```

Of course, that's not *quite* what you need, because you still want the other commits.  So now you must copy `B` to `B'` as well.  The—or at least *a*—difference between `B` and the new `B'` is that `B'`'s parent is `A'`, not `A`.  The existing `B` has the existing `A` as its parent, and you *cannot change any existing commit*.

So now you extract `B` (and perhaps remove those same files again, if that's part of your goal), then make new commit `B'` whose parent is `A'`:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- old-master

A'-B'   <-- new-master
```

Obviously, you're still not done yet.  You must now copy `C` to `C'` in the same way you copied `B` to `B'`, then repeat for the rest of the commits.  Eventually you wind up with this:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- old-master

A'-B'-C'-D'-E'-F'  <-- new-master
```

and now you can use the new chain of commits as `master` and you are done (well, except for creating the new branch(es), which must be done separately—you drew them as having `B` attached to the last commit in the new branch, but I suspect you didn't quite mean it that way).

There is a Git command that does exactly this: `git filter-branch`.  The `git filter-branch` command takes the branch(es) you name on the command line, finds every commit reachable from those names (hence `F` then `E` then `D` then ... then `A`), puts them into the right order (`A` first, etc), and begins copying:

- extract original commit;
- apply each filter, in the order listed in [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html);
- make a new commit whose parent(s) is/are the parent(s) made earlier during the filtering process (or for an original root, make a new root commit).

Once all the specified commits have been copied, `git filter-branch` adjusts the branch names to point to the final copied commits.

Typically, to do an entire repository, you use `--all` to copy *all* commits and adjust *all* branch names, along with `--tag-name-filter cat` to adjust all tag names.  You can use the `--tree-filter` as it's the simplest: it lets you use ordinary file system operations on ordinary files, to manipulate the contents of each commit.  But it's also the *slowest* filter, by far; so you may want to experiment until you can do the file-removal with the fastest filter, which is the `--index-filter`.

(You'll still need to build the new branch separately, as `git filter-branch` only changes any *existing* branch names, and builds a map of old-to-new commit hashes as it goes.  It—unlike the [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), which in some ways is better-designed—*removes* this map when it is done, but for your particular purposes you won't need it, you can just find the new root commit.  It's wisest to experiment on a clone of the repository, probably a `git clone --mirror` clone.)

Answer (score 1):

Try rebasing from root using [interactive mode](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode):

```
git rebase --interactive --root
```

And then use *edit* command on the first commit.

Comment: Rebasing interactively will make possible only to edit the comment, but will not allow to delete any directory.

Comment: @klor: Git doesn't save directories, it only saves files. Later, when you *extract* the commit, if Git must, it will create a directory to hold them. If you remove all the files within a directory, and make a new commit from that, you get a commit that doesn't force Git to create the directory to extract the files.

Comment: You can edit the commit contents using *edit* instead of *pick* or *reword*. Something like this is explained in Splitting Commit section -> https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_splitting_commits

Answer (score -1):

You can't just remove a directory from an old commit.
If you are several commits after the initial I think the best thing to do is:

- create a new branch for every directory
- work on the directory in its branch
- merge the updates on master branch

If you were on the commit right after the initial, you could do a `git reset --soft` to go to the initial commit and keep your changes.

Comment: It is a big project. I have a lot directories, a lot commits, can not create new branch for each directory. I remember, there is some history rewrite feature, which might be used. Don't know, if it is relevant for this case.

Comment: ok didn't know that, unfortunately you can't remove dirs from old commits, maybe someone else has an answer for you :)